# Navigate relationship and further constrain result set with query

Tags: perl, dbix-class

Given a db schema like this

```sql
create table account (
 id     serial primary key,
 no     varchar
);
create type  sourcetype as enum ('TYPE_A','TYPE_B');
create table orgunit (
 id     serial primary key,
 name   varchar,
 source sourcetype
);
-- N:M-Relationship between Accounts and OrgUnits
create table orgunitaccount (
 orgunitid int references orgunit(id),
 accountid int references account(id)
);
```

Using `dbicdump` on this schema results in the following classes (note, that I cut out the comments):

```perl
use utf8;
package RelTest::Result::Account;
use strict;
use warnings;
use base 'DBIx::Class::Core';
__PACKAGE__->table("account");
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "id",
  {
    data_type         => "integer",
    is_auto_increment => 1,
    is_nullable       => 0,
    sequence          => "account_id_seq",
  },
  "no",
  {
    data_type   => "text",
    is_nullable => 1,
    original    => { data_type => "varchar" },
  },
);
__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key("id");
__PACKAGE__->has_many(
  "orgunitaccounts",
  "RelTest::Result::Orgunitaccount",
  { "foreign.accountid" => "self.id" },
  { cascade_copy => 0, cascade_delete => 0 },
);
1;

use utf8;
package RelTest::Result::Orgunit;
__PACKAGE__->table("orgunit");
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "id",
  {
    data_type         => "integer",
    is_auto_increment => 1,
    is_nullable       => 0,
    sequence          => "orgunit_id_seq",
  },
  "name",
  {
    data_type   => "text",
    is_nullable => 1,
    original    => { data_type => "varchar" },
  },
  "source",
  {
    data_type => "enum",
    extra => { custom_type_name => "sourcetype", list => ["TYPE_A", "TYPE_B"] },
    is_nullable => 1,
  },
);
__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key("id");
__PACKAGE__->has_many(
  "orgunitaccounts",
  "RelTest::Result::Orgunitaccount",
  { "foreign.orgunitid" => "self.id" },
  { cascade_copy => 0, cascade_delete => 0 },
);
1;

use utf8;
package RelTest::Result::Orgunitaccount;
__PACKAGE__->table("orgunitaccount");
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "orgunitid",
  { data_type => "integer", is_foreign_key => 1, is_nullable => 1 },
  "accountid",
  { data_type => "integer", is_foreign_key => 1, is_nullable => 1 },
);
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to(
  "accountid",
  "RelTest::Result::Account",
  { id => "accountid" },
  {
    is_deferrable => 0,
    join_type     => "LEFT",
    on_delete     => "NO ACTION",
    on_update     => "NO ACTION",
  },
);
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to(
  "orgunitid",
  "RelTest::Result::Orgunit",
  { id => "orgunitid" },
  {
    is_deferrable => 0,
    join_type     => "LEFT",
    on_delete     => "NO ACTION",
    on_update     => "NO ACTION",
  },
);
1;
```

See the complete sample code in [this](https://github.com/sschober/dbix-rel-navigation-and-query) github repository.

I am looking for way to navigate this relationship starting from `account` towards the set of `orgunit`s *further constraining* which `orgunit`s I want to select, *based an attributes of the target table* (`account`). My current approach is the following:

```perl
my $schema  = $schemaPkg->connect(...); # not important
my $account = 
   $schema->resultset('Account')->search( number => $acctNumber )->single();
my $typeBAccounts = 
   grep { $_->orgunitid->source eq 'TYPE_B'}
   $account->orgunitaccounts();
```

My question is: Is there a way to incorporate this constraint into the navigational commands, like with `search( <queryHashRef> )`?

Note, that I know that I cann specify a query in the call to `orgunitaccounts()`, but that is only scoped to the `orgunitaccount` table, whereas I want to constrain the set based on an attribute of `account`.

Comment: Please paste the DBIx::Class resultsources instead of the DDL statements so it's easier to help you. You should also use find instead of search when you want to fetch a single row, in your case by defining a unique constraint for the number column and using that.

Comment: I know, I can use find to acquire a single result, but that is not the point of my question. ;) The resultsources are a bit lonigsh... but I'll do my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you'd want to call search on the ResultSet you want to get Result objects from, in your case that seems to be Orgunits.
So why not do something like:

```
my $rs_orgunits = $schema->resultset('Orgunit')->search({
        source => 'TYPE_B',
        'accountid.number' => $acctNumber,
    },
    {
        join => { orgunitaccounts => 'acountid' },
    });
```

If you have the account object already for some other reason you don't need to join `accountid` but search for `orgunitaccounts.accountid => $account` instead.

Another possibility is to use search_related.

Comment: Ah, so it comes down to not using the navigational methods at all, but using joins. Reading up on the join syntax right now, thank you!

Comment: Just for completeness’ sake I've [implemented](https://github.com/sschober/dbix-rel-navigation-and-query/tree/solution) your suggestion in my sample project on a solution branch.

Comment: Great but please don't use DBIX as an acronym for DBIx::Class. It's an entire namespace where plenty of other projects exist. The common abbreviation is DBIC.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I always wondered why it was `dbicdump`! :)

Comment: I [renamed](https://github.com/sschober/dbic-rel-navigation-and-query) that github repo to reflect your comment.